# Is it possible to fire a delete trigger by adjusting TTL value in CosmosDB?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a pre-delete trigger by using Script Explorer in Azure portal. The below trigger is written in JavaScript:

```
function markReminderAsPastDue() {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var request = getContext().getRequest();
var docToCreate = request.getBody();
docToCreate["pastDue"] = true;
docToCreate["id"] = "";
var accepted = collection.createDocument(collection.getSelfLink(),
    docToCreate,
    function (err, documentCreated) {
        if (err) throw new Error('Error' + err.message);
    });
if (!accepted) throw new Error("Document creation not accepted");
```

}

I set the TTL value for each document in the associated collection. So the TTL value is not equal to -1 and documents are deleted automatically once the time expires.If I delete the document manually, the pre-delete trigger is fired. However, when the document is deleted implicitly because of the TTL value, the trigger is not fired. What should I do to fix this problem? Is it possible to make triggers fire with TTL value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no callback mechanism of any sort in Azure Cosmos DB for TTL. The TTL enforcement is just a background thread that queries every second for documents that have expired, then deletes them.

Combined with your needs, I'd suggest you just mimicking the TTL operation in your application layer, where you can perform whatever extra business logic.

You can set an update time attribute in each document, which updates the update times for each modification. Then do a polling mechanism at your application layer and iterate through the database every once in a while to find out the data when the update time expires and delete them.

In order to reduce the pressure on your application layer, you can give the action of deleting data to [Cosmos DB Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: 2 years later, has this changed? Can we fire a trigger when the TTL background job deletes an item?

Comment: 6 years later, has this changed? Can we fire a trigger when the TTL background job deletes an item?